# Is it possible to tell if a character has the capability of lying?

Tags: logic

This question is born out of the riddle where there are two characters, one that always lies and one that always tells the truth, and you want them to tell you which of two doors is the "good" or "bad" door. You can ask either character, "what would the other character say is the good door?" And the lier will answer with the bad door, and the truther will also answer with the bad door.

My question is a variation, given two characters where each character might always tell the truth, or might always lie, but both characters think the other always tells the truth, are there any questions you can ask that allow you to determine more information about the composition?

For example it could be that character A and B both always tell the truth (and each thinks the other always tells the truth) or it could be that character A and B both always lie (but again each thinks the other always tells the truth), or it could be that one character always tells the truth and the other always lies (but again they both think the other always tells the truth).

Are there any questions that can be asked to determine the composition?

Comment: As phrased, everyone *believes* that everyone else is a truth teller, so detecting a liar is easy:  just ask A if B always tells the truth.  You then know whether A is a truth teller or a liar, at which point you can ask about doors.

Answer (score 0):

Like Xander Henderson pointed out in the comments, you can determine if either of them is a liar or a truth-teller in one question. However, you cannot determine the identities of *both* characters simultaneously via just one question that only one of them will answer, since neither of them knows anything about the other. In order to determine character X's identity, we need to hear a response from character X.

Here are some more facts about this situation: We could alternatively, in a single question, determine which door is correct. However, we cannot simultaneously determine the identity of either character and which door is correct in a single question.

Try to think about why these facts are true. To see the first, construct a sentence similar to the question constructed in the original problem. To see the second, think about how much information can be encoded in a single yes/no response.